# C# exe running issue with EMGU CV

Tags: c#, exe, emgucv, computer-vision

I have been working on Microsoft Visual C# 2010 for an image processing program. The software uses EMGU CV 2.4.0. The program is very long (consists of 8 very lengthy functions) so i cannot post it here. Now, the program works perfectly on my pc. I have finished it. I can just run the exe file, and it works. My problem is that the .exe file doesnt work on another computer. Actually, I have 2 separate projects, But both are using EMGU CV. No error message  shows to me when I run the first exe on another pc ( although it shows to me sometimes that ( project1 stopped working, windows is trying to collect information, this might take minutes ) but that's not always. Now the error message that shows to me when i run the second exe on another pc is (microsoft .net framework, EMGU.CV.CVInvoke exception error). then the exe work and a window appear ( which is expected ) but the real task of the program which is doing some image processing is not being done.
Note that both of the projects are windows applications output type. 
Note that .NET framework 4 client profile is the target framework

I don't think this is .NET framework issue. Because I have tried to do a simple program and the exe file works on the other pc (it was just a simple streamwriter program which creates .txt) These are the EMGU CV libraries I'm using:

```
EMGU.CV.dll
EMGU.CV.GPU.dll
EMGU.CV.UI.dll
EMGU.CV.UTIL.dll
```

Just for your information, I have downloaded EMGU CV 2.4.0 on the other pc as well ( after failing in running it with putting the libraries with the .exe in 1 file ) but still nothing works. I have no clue what on earth can be the problem!
I don't know if this is useful, but the program uses SURFFEATURE example as the one in the EMGU CV but with lots and lots of modifications ( I have worked on it since the last Novermber) and basically it is a program for object recognition purpose.

Answer (score 1):

have you installed the [Visual C++ redistributibale](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328) on the machine, you are trying to run the file on?

If it's a x64 machine you will need the [x64 version](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13523). But I would still also install the x86 version, just in case...

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question but..

If your OS is 64 bit you should use EmguCV x64 but if your OS is 32 bit then use x86 dlls. I built my solution as 'Any CPU' and it still worked. 
Also as @Pogo the Jotz mentioned, you need to install Visual C++ Redistributable on that machine, same as on your visual studio version in which you compiled your exe file. The .Net framework also should be the same.